# Impossible to install R package "ssh"

Tags: r, ssh, libssh

thank you for reading!
I am using RStudio on a macOS 11.0.1 and have tried every way I know of to install the "ssh" package.

I attempted to install the package using the following methods:

- in R: `remotes::install_github('ropensci/ssh')`
- in R: `install.packages("ssh")`
- in the terminal: `brew install libssh`
- downloading the tar.gz file and installing it in R

Unfortunately, none of the above options work. I am able to install all other packages without any issue, but this is the only one not working.

Please let me know if you can assist! I included the error messages below.

R error message:

```
Configuration failed because libssh was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssh-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libssh-devel (Fedora, EPEL)
 * brew: libssh (OSX)
If libssh is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libssh.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
-------------------------- [ERROR MESSAGE] ------------------------------
<stdin>:1:10: fatal error: 'libssh/libssh.h' file not found
#include <libssh/libssh.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘ssh’
* removing ‘/Users/workaccount/Library/R/4.0/library/ssh’
Error: Failed to install 'ssh' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/var/folders/4k/ctwszrd55rd5dtz1md89dmwc0000gp/T//RtmpmrThYs/file76e6cdeaf7c/ssh_0.7.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Terminal error message:

```
touch: /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
touch: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
fatal: Unable to create '/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
fatal: Unable to create '/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
    11: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `<main>'
    10: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `require_relative'
     9: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:37:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os.rb:21:in `<module:OS>'
     4: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:58:in `prerelease?'
     3: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:24:in `version'
     2: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:24:in `new'
     1: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/version.rb:23:in `initialize'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/version.rb:368:in `initialize': Version value must be a string; got a NilClass () (TypeError)
```

Comment: Your Homebrew is configured incorrectly. You need to fix *that* issue. In fact, it looks as if your Homebrew was installed by a different user, is that possible? As far as I know, Homebrew doesn’t really support shared systems that have more than one user. You may need to completely remove the `/usr/local` folder and re-install Homebrew. But note that this might make the other user, who initially installed Homebrew, quite unhappy.

Comment: I found this information when I looked into your issue: https://github.com/ropensci/git2r/issues/426 -- njspix wrote that "Apparently this is caused by Homebrew not symlinking openssl/libssh2..." at the end of the conversation.

Comment: Thank you @KonradRudolph, I had recently created a new user on my mac but didn't think it would pose any issues.... I proceeded to freshly reinstall R and Homebrew and it solved my problems. Cheers!